# Weird sound in my Pulsar 220

Tags: engine, motorcycle, vibration, bajaj, pulsar

Recently I had bought the new pulsar 220F (about 8 months ago) and now I am facing a strange sound in my bike. First the bike seems to work in normal condition and after 5 10 minutes, the bike feel like it's tired now. Engine become harsh and vibrate little more than normal condition. Pick up also decreases. In normal condition I could go to 40 kmph in 3 gears easily. But when the sound changes and pick up decreases, it gives a harsh sound in 3 gears when I reach to 37 - 38 kmph. I am also facing low mileage (about 25 kmpl) in city traffic.

I even went to bajaj showroom long time ago and they said tappet was too tight and they fixed it. But the problem is same now.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Considering this is a new bike, it is recommended you take it back to the dealership where you purchased it. If you try to fix things yourself, it may void the warranty.

Comment: Doesn't anyone here have recommendations for this problem?

Comment: Running on a wrong type of engine oil might make symptoms like these. Correct me if wrong.

Comment: Does the quality of petrol also affect in the vibration? @devst3r

Comment: No, i don't think so. quality of petrol affects the carb mostly and may lose pickup and mileage. How many kilometers covered?

Comment: I have covered just 2500 km. The latest thing I realized is I was having the same problem (vibration and decreased pickup) then I went for a long ride which covered 410 km. After that my was running smooth like butter no problems at all. Now again this morning, 2 days after the trip when I changed gear, the same vibration and low pickup problem started again.

Comment: Have you had any recent maintenance done to the bike, something which might tally with the perceived lack of performance?

Answer (score 2):

Since the Motorcycle is new and is on warranty period, As CharlieRB suggested, you have to take the bike to an authorized dealer and explain them the problems.
Below i have described some possible situations that match your problem.

1. Chain alignment issue

An improper chain alignment can cause vibrations and rattling in higher speeds and also in different gears. In most of the pulsar bikes, the chain will touch the center stand when it is loose. make sure the sound is coming from the engine side.

2. Cam Chain / Timing Chain

If the sound is from the engine, it could be because of a loose cam chain and can also be heard slightly even in idle state. In this case you just have to ask mechanics to tight the cam chain inside the engine.

3. Spark Knock

As described in this website ([website link](http://dannysengineportal.com/what-is-engine-spark-knock/)), the some signs of a spark knock pretty much matches your problems. It might not be a spark knock at all, try running on a octane petrol. premium or speed petrol as we say in India. If there is no such problems after, there is a chance of spark knock.